# How can I get the last changed date of a file that has moved to a different path?

Tags: git

Is there a Git command that will return the date of the last **file contents update commit**?

I am using this to track the date of the last markdown file modification:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%aI -- <PATH>/<TO>/<FILE>.md
```

The problem is that if the **file path** changes, the command will return the date of the **last rename/move** commit, which I would rather omit.

Is this doable with just Git, or would I have to use a bash script to traverse the logs?

Comment: Git doesn't really track files as much as we would like. If the content changes enough and the path also changes then git doesn't see them as the same file.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, I am aware of this. In this specific case, the content updates would be  probably rather minor text edits (but I didn't think of a case when *both* the content *and* the path is updated in one commit – that shouldn't be ignored).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a bit of scripting on top of :

```
git log --follow --name-status --pretty=format:%aI -- path/to/file.md
```

Here is an example, output, with one exact move (no content modification) :

```
$ git log --follow --name-status --pretty=format:%aI -- path/to/file.md
2021-12-07T16:39:43+01:00
M       path/to/file.md

2021-12-07T16:18:59+01:00
R100    old/path/to/file.md  path/to/file.md

2021-12-07T15:37:15+01:00
A       old/path/to/file.md
```

So you can parse lines one after the other :

1. store parsed date
2. parse beginning of the status line
3. if lines starts with `R100` (file renamed, not modified), keep parsing
4. otherwise, the date stored in step 1. is the date you are looking for

Comment: Thank you. As far as I understand it (currently testing), the `R100 …` line apears if just the *path* changes, not the *contents* (it's not present if I update *both* in a single commit). Am I right?

Comment: @HynekS : yes, that's it